# Not able to get the list of months between a range of dates that include the current months as well

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two dates given in a list and i need to print the no. of months between these two dates. The output needs to be the name of months in chronological order i.e. Jan  comes before August. The input date ranges would never be more than 12 months apart.

The Code below-
`code`

````
import pandas as pd
# import ast,sys
# input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = [2017,8,2,2018,1,1]
d1=datetime.date(input_list[0],input_list[1],input_list[2])
print(d1)
d2=datetime.date(input_list[3],input_list[4],input_list[5])
print(d2)
months= pd.date_range(d1,d2, 
              freq='MS').strftime("%B").tolist()
months
# months_sorted = sorted(months, key=lambda months: datetime.strftime(months, "%b"))
# months_sorted```

Produces the output
['September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January']
It should also have included August and sorting is also not working. Any help?
````

Answer (score 1):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and change format to `%B` for match full month names:

```
months_sorted = sorted(months, key=lambda months: datetime.datetime.strptime(months, "%B"))
print (months_sorted)
['January', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```